# RStudio: git clone another branch

Tags: git, rstudio, git-fork

By default when creating a new project in RStudio it clones the master branch.

On my side I dont have write access to the master branch. I have forked a repository and created a development branch called "dev"
Is there a way to create a new RStudio project that works on this development branch only?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can handle the branches within your RStudio environment - it's really easy:
1. [Choose an existing branch and point the project on it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sf9JP.png)
2. [Create a new branch within a RStudio project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Opl8A.png)
[Further infos about using version control within RStudio](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200532077?version=1.2.1335&mode=desktop)

Comment: in other words, Rstudio clones all branches, and `checkout` to the master or main branch per default, but you can go to any branch later on.

Answer (score 1):

If you have forked the repository, you do have access to the `master` branch of that fork.

If you need `master` for your project to work, you can work on that branch.